# static transform publisher - launch file

Tags: ros, kinect, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I have different frames which I create with the static transform publisher in a launch file, for example:

I work with a kinect and get from the kinect_aux node the actuel angle from the tilted position from the kinect back. (cur_tilt_angle)
So my question is, is it possible that instead I write a fixed value like 1.57, I get this cur_tilt_angle in the launch file?

Thank you for help.

(I use ROS electric.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57079/static-transform-publisher---launch-file/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to write a node that listens to that particular topic and publishes your required tf. With a static transform publisher only fixed transforms can be published.

If it is not a topic but a parameter stored in the parameter server, then yes, you can use that parameter and load it to the static transform publisher. Take a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/param).

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on 2013-03-04**:
Ok, thank you.

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-03-04**:
Please, accept the answer if that is the correct one

**Comment by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on 2013-08-07**:
@Miquel Massot  @JaRu can you please refer to me an example code where "write a node that listens to that particular topic and publishes your required tf" is implemented.

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-08-03**:
@Gudjohnson I would take a look at the "Writing a tf broadcaster (C++)" tutorial example, here: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20(C%2B%2B)